# Ideal Gradle configuration what does create separate module per source set do?Will he change his dependency?

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, source-sets

Ideal Gradle configuration what does create separate module per source set do?Will he change his dependency?I don't see any change when I don't check, except that there are two modules in the IDE.What does this mean?I'm a beginner.

Comment: https://github.com/fanmingyi/myImg/blob/master/TIM%E5%9B%BE%E7%89%8720190609151229.png

Answer (score 1):

In Gradle each source set has it's own classpath. When you use **Create separate module per source set** option IDE [creates separate module](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-projects.html#gradle_source_sets) for the source set so that its own classpath.

But note that this option does not work with Android projects.